# How caching works in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, caching, phantomjs

I am following the [Command Line Interface](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html) document given in the PhantomJS site.

As per the document, it says for caching `disk-cache` value should be set as true. And you can also set the size of the cached file in the `max-disk-cache-size` option.

I am testing the caching in the PhantomJs. For this, I have written a script, which looks like this -

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');

page.onResourceRequested = function(request) {
  console.log('Request ' + request.url);
};
page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
  console.log('Receive ' + response.url + '  Size: ' + response.bodySize);
};
page.open(system.args[1], function(status) {
  console.log("Status: " + status);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

I am running the script in terminal with the command -

```
phantomjs --disk-cache=true --max-disk-cache-size=10000 phantom-test.js http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-requested.html
```

In my script, I am printing the requested resources and the received resources. And when I run the script with the above command I can still see it's requesting all the resources for the page.

Also, I went to the `Library/Caches/Ofi Labs/PhantomJS` directory in my Mac and I don't see any changes there. How can I verify if PhantomJs is caching the files or not?

Also, I don't see much of a difference in the page load time for the first load and the successive page loads after that. If it were caching then there should be a significant difference in the page load time.

Comment: Is the file you're loading bigger than the cache size you've set?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I ran again with the size `--max-disk-cache-size=1000000`. No change though.